# Does Etcher replace rEFInd?

Tags: unix, efi

Installing Linux on a Mac has always been complicated by the need for running [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

Yet Ubuntu's [instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos) for installing on a Mac mention Etcher (step 3), but do not mention rEFInd.

Can you confirm that to completely displace macOS and end up with a single-boot Mac running Ubuntu, these instructions are sufficient, and there is no need to run rEFInd?

Comment: @klanomath If I install Ubuntu through Etcher, and if I intend to wipe the disk and seek a clean Ubuntu install, do I still need rEFInd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a clean install of Ubuntu on a Mac without needing to install rEFInd.

The procedure for installing depends on the model Mac and the version of Ubuntu.

The rEFInd boot manager can be useful in the following situations.

- You want a menu with operating system choices to appear each time the computer boots or reboots.
- You want to select the default operating system to boot from the currently executing operation system.

rEFInd is a boot manager. This means rEFInd does not actually boot an operating system. rEFInd just instructs the firmware which operating system to boot.

Since you wish to only install Ubuntu on your Mac, then there is no reason to install the rEFInd boot manager.